# TFS 2010 TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

i have installed TFS 2010 on WS 2008 R2 more than two years and every things worked fins till i have installed an app on the server which i think it change some seting on IIS/server. and after that i can not access tfs web services even on the TFS server localy!!.
what is the problem.
after that for resolving all security issues I changed TFS applicaion pool's identification to network administrator. tfs account is NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. i can create team project collection from the tfs administration console. i checked network traffic with fiddler for accessing http:///tfs and response was:

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 16 Dec 2014 11:49:24 GMT
Content-Length: 0

[image]

Comment: Is TFS really running on port 5050? The default is 8080

Answer (score 0):

If you have broken the server by installing something then I would recommend building a new dedicated TFS server.

Option 1) Create a new clean server for TFS. Install SQL and restore all of the databases from your old server. Then install TFS 2013. 
Option 2) if you do not have room for a dedicated TFS server you should create a temporary instance to get working and then push all of your data to VSO (http://tfs.visualstudio.com)

If you run TFS locally you should be aware that TFS owned both the server and the database server that it is installed on. It is an application that includes those components.